# How do I generate a random number between -1000 and 1000?

Tags: java

Good day,

I am coding the "Guess the number" game in java and I'm trying to get the program to generate a number between -1000 and 1000 but for some reason, it only generates numbers above 1 right now.

What exactly have I done wrong here? 
Could anybody help me out?

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    int numberToGuess = rand.nextInt((1000 - (-1000) + 1) + (-1000));
    int numberOfTries = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int guess;
    boolean win = false;

    System.out.println("Lets begin.");

    while (win == false && numberOfTries < 11) {

        System.out.println("Insert a number:");
        guess = input.nextInt();
        numberOfTries++;


        if (guess == numberToGuess) {
            win = true;
        }

        else if (guess < numberToGuess) {
        System.out.println("Your guess is too low.");
        }

        else if (guess > numberToGuess) {
        System.out.println("Your guess it too high.");
        }


    }

    if (win == true)
    System.out.println("You won with " + numberOfTries + " attempts. The hidden number was " + numberToGuess + ".");

    else if (numberOfTries == 11) {
        System.out.println("You lost. The number was " + numberToGuess + ".");
    }



}


}
```

Comment: `new Random().nextInt(2000) - 1000`

Comment: `rand.nextInt((1000 - (-1000) + 1) + (-1000))` is the same as `rand.nextInt(1001)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int numberToGuess = rand.nextInt(2001) -1000;
```

Think of the # inside the paranthesis as the span the random # can reach.  Add 1 to your span because .nextInt upper Bound is exclusive.  Then you want to translate that span from 0 to 2000 to -1000 to 1000 using subtraction.

Comment: Thank you so very much! You managed to explain it to me very well and everything is working perfectly now. Thanks once again!

Comment: No problem.  Thanks for contributing and please accept my answer (:

Comment: [`nextInt(int bound)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) is *upper-exclusive*, so `nextInt(2000)` returns a number between 0 and 1999 *(inclusive)*. To get number between -1000 and 1000 *(inclusive)*, you need `rand.nextInt(2001) - 1000`

Answer (score 0):

```
   int numberToGuess = rand.nextInt((1000 - (-1000) + 1) + (-1000));
```

you have 1000 and -1000 so it will be zero , using rand.nextInt()

```
        rand.nextInt(2001) -1000;
```

using Math.random()

```
       (int)(Math.random() *2001 +1) - 1001
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using below

```
int numberToGuess  = rand.nextInt((1000 - (-1000)) + 1) + (-1000);
```

And I'm getting below results

```
-727
-971
-339
84
295
498
....
```

Comment: Really? I tried numerous times and never got the result under 0 for some reason.

Comment: Yes. I guess why its not working for you is because the loop is just of 11.. Do one thing, run the loop for 100 times, and comment out rest of the code for a min.
I believe you'll see the negative numbers. If it does, like my answer.

Comment: That's not what he had above.  You're off by a ")".

Answer (score 0):

use another random number to decide the sign.

```
    int numberToGuess = rand.nextInt(1001);
    int sign = rand.nextInt(2);
    if(sign==0){
        numberToGuess*=-1;
    }
```